HAVING clause can't deal with column of window function?
I have such MySQL code:
SELECT 
    departmentId, 
    name, 
    salary, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY departmentId ORDER BY salary DESC) AS salary_rank
FROM Employee
HAVING departmentId = 1

This works properly as expected but if I change the HAVING clause as
SELECT 
    departmentId, 
    name, 
    salary, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY departmentId ORDER BY salary DESC) AS salary_rank
FROM Employee
HAVING salary_rank = 1

It wouldn't get passed.
Why HAVING clause is not abled to do such filtering, for HAVING clause "taking effect after query"?

Why do you use HAVING without GROUP BY? That's mostly no Standard SQL and no good idea. Use a WHERE clause. There are some rar cases where HAVING without GROUP BY is correct and required. But this here doesn't seem to be such an edge case.

The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/select.html

Also note you should please provide some sample input data and the expected result of your query, otherwise people don't know what you talk about.

As to why you get the error Error Code: 3594. You cannot use the alias 'salary_rank' of an expression containing a window function in this context is probably best answered by the mysql developers. and you should publish the full error message you see..


Why HAVING clause is not abled to do such filtering, for HAVING clause "taking effect after query"?

Formally, it should be assumed that window functions are processed/evaluated after processing the HAVING clause and calculating all output columns, except those in expressions for which some window function is used, but before processing the ORDER BY.
Thus, expressions that use window functions have not yet been evaluated at the time of processing the HAVING clause.

While MySQL has overloaded the HAVING operator to allow referring to aliases, it does not work with window functions.  The reason for this is that the window functions generally evaluate last in the pipeline.  This means that, in your second query, the dense rank calculation would not have completed when it would be needed to filter.  In this case, the workaround is to simply use a proper subquery:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT departmentId, name, salary, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY departmentId ORDER BY salary DESC) AS salary_rank
    FROM Employee
)

SELECT departmentId, name, salary
FROM cte
WHERE salary_rank = 1;


try the following:
WITH RankedEmployees AS (
SELECT
departmentId,
name,
salary,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY departmentId ORDER BY salary DESC) AS salary_rank
)
SELECT
departmentId,
name,
salary
FROM RankedEmployees
WHERE salary_rank = 1;

Your answer is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/79300903/724039, but yours lacks proper formatting, and the needed extra explanation.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
